# parsing list in JSON without curly braces in android-java

Tags: android, json, arrays

I am trying to read a list from JSON format into Android Java.

I **can read** ***children*** using `getJSONarray()`. But **unable** to read values of **message** or **email**.

*Seems getJSONarray() doesnt work for what i want.*

Yes, i am using `getJSONObject` on **children** to extract message. But how do i extract **individual values** after getting message array?

```
{
  "children": [{
    "message": ["message1","message2","message3"],
    "email": ["email1",
              "email2"]
  }, {
    "message": ["message1", "message2", "message3"],
    "email": ["email1", "email2"]
  }]
}
```

I know how to extract from:

```
  {
      "children": [{
                     "message1": "message___1"
                     "message2": "message___2"
                     "message3": "message___3"

          }]
}
```

But not when it is all in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below code:

```
for(int i=0; i<childrenArray.length(); i++)
{
JSONObject childObj=childrenArray.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray messageArray=childObj.getJSONArray("message");
    for(int j=0; j<messageArray.length();j++
        {
            //here get value from messageArray.getString(j) or messageArray.getJSONObject(j), whichever applicable
        }

JSONArray emailArray=childObj.getJSONArray("email");
    for(int k=0; k<emailArray.length();k++
        {
            //here get value from emailArray.getString(k) or emailArray.getJSONObject(k), whichever applicable
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do once you've got the `JSONArray` of "children" is to then extract the individual `JSONObjects` one by one like so:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < childArray.length(); counter++) { 
    //Get the next item
    JSONObject nextobj = childArray.getJSONObject(counter);
```

Then you can extract your message and email arrays from your `nextobj` variable. This is because each "message" and "email" is not directly accessible from your "children" `JSONArray`, they're wrapped up in `JSONObjects`

Comment: *Yes, i am using getJSONobject on children to extract message. But how do i extract individual values after getting message array?

Comment: I want to extract values from a list. and these values bear no indexes apparently to use getJSONObject on them.